# Jailcoder how to

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I just tried to get my own app on my iPhone without a developer account. The following are steps I did:

1. I patched Xcode and my project (Currency.xcodeproj) with JailCoder
2. I want to build the project with "iOS device" in Xcode. But I got a error message like "no device found". So I ran it in the emulator and I got the currency.app-file in /Users/Dogan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Currency-gjxrulouxbmjslbzslsplyehgfgm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
3. SSH to iPhone in /var/mobile/Applications
4. Creating a new folder named FADE9826-4878-4458-B5BE-90AD4EB60FDF (I have to take a valid UDID. Have I use to specific tools to create a UDID? I have the UDID from an other example). I also created a directory in this folder with the name "Documents".
5. chown -R mobile FADE9826-4878-4458-B5BE-90AD4EB60FDF
6. scp -r Currency.app root@IP-ADRESS-OF-IPHONE:/var/mobile/Applications/FADE9826-4878-4458-B5BE-90AD4EB60FDF/
7. Restarting Springboard in SSH with "killall SpringBoard"

I got the app, but it doesn't work. Every time on click, it crashes and kicks me to the home screen. Had I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

You missed that simulator builds don't work on iPhones, because they are built for the wrong CPU type. Simulator builds are Intel x86 apps, and the iPhone has an ARM CPU.

There might be other problems (I don't know how jailcoder works) but there's no way you're getting the simulator build running on the phone.

Comment: ok, and how can i buid on ios device without an dev account to create  the *.app file?

Comment: i read that i have to patch a new installation of xcode. so if my xcode still was in use, i have to remove and install it again. is it right?

Comment: Only that you're going to a lot of trouble to avoid signing up for Apple's developer program.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading Jailcoder and going through the guided patch of Xcode and then patching your project, if your device is plugged into your computer, select the target type (where you can select simulator, iOS Device, etc.) and there should be a listing of your device's name.

Comment: Don't know how, but after opening and closing xcode, xCode organizer recognized my ipod. I was able to run and debug the app in it. Maybe this might help somebody else :)